# How to get Document.SelfLink in Pre trigger?

Tags: javascript, c#, azure-cosmosdb

New query! :)

I have this following *Pre trigger* defined on my collection, where I get the main Document ID and put it inside an inner Document in the same Document. Now how do I also get the SelfLink of the main document. Here is what I have tried so far, without success?

```
function updateMetadata() {
 var context = getContext();
 var request = context.getRequest();
 var item = request.getBody();
 var typeName = item["typename"]; 
 item[typeName].mainDocId = item.id;  // works fine
 //item[typeName].objSelfLink = item._self; //does not work
 //item[typeName].objSelfLink = item.self; //does not work
 //item[typeName].objSelfLink = item.selflink; //does not work
 //item[typeName].objSelfLink = item.Self; //does not work
 //item[typeName].objSelfLink = item.selfLink; //does not work
 request.setBody(item);
}
```

The Id gets sets just fine. Is this because I do this in a *Pre trigger* and the SelfLink is not present/accessible in *Pre trigger*?? 
The following [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/) does state that:

```
The request object can be used to manipulate the request message associated with the operation. 
Here, the pre-trigger is being run with the creation of a document, 
and the request message body contains the document to be created in JSON format.
```

But then I would assume that the Id would also not be generated in *Pre trigger* maybe, if the SelfLink is not being generated. Can someone please point me towards any relevant documentation please??

Comment: I suspect that you are right. It's not there in pre-triggers. `._self` is correct. The reason the `.id` might be there is that it may be generated client side. I'm not using .NET but I suspect that there is some option to generate the id's client side. It's unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish? If you explain why you want to annotate the item with an additional reference to the _self, I may be able to make some suggestions.

Comment: As per @LarryMaccherone above, what is the use case you are trying to accomplish? The result of the insert / replace operation will have the object which will include the _self and other system metadata. 

from the code supplied "updateMetadata", are you trying to update the system properties? this is not supported. they are read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. _self is not yet available because the record has not yet been written. ID is generated client side in all the SDKs.

If you want access to the _self link then consider a post-trigger, i.e. after the record has been written.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Well unfortunately it does not actually help me since I needed to persist the SelfLink, like the Id, when creating a new Document without doing a duplicate save (in the post-trigger) of the same record. 
Also since I am assuming that if I do a save, in the post-trigger, of the same Document again there a *$ cost* associated with it, unlike doing a simple request.setBody(item) in Pre-trigger.

Comment: The trigger example posted above doesn't include any code for checking duplicates. Would you mind posting the logic for checking for duplicates for this scenario? In other words, what are the set properties are you enforcing an unique constraint on? Uniqueness on the `id` property is already enforced, as it is treated as the primary key for a document.. and `_self` is guaranteed by the system to be unique.